# Track Mutiple GA Events on a singluar element

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

This is a "basic" question, but know there is a larger technical block for this. I've been looking around and have not been able to find a question similar this.

Scenario:
I have a form which is part of a responsive site that sends both Desktop and Mobile form fills as conversions into Adwords.

The form is the same for Desktop and Mobile so there is only one "submit" button for the form, however, I want to know whether it was a Mobile form submit or a Desktop form submit, hence Google Analytics can only track one or the other, right? I use "m_form_submit" for mobile and "d_form_submit" for desktop.

So I guess my question is:
Is there a way I can track 2(or more) GA events on a singular element without having the user trigger both events at once?

Ideally: tell GA I want to serve *this* event for Mobile and *that* event for Desktop?

Comment: How are you differentiating between mobile and desktop? Screen size? User Agent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tagged this question with "jQuery" so I assume you're using jQuery to listen for the form submit and then send the events to GA.

All you need to go do only send the event associated with the mobile or desktop version is a simple conditional check before sending:

```
$('#myform').one('submit', function(e) {

  // Prevent form from submitting, and then submit once the GA hit succeeds.
  e.preventDefault();

  // Change this to whatever you're using to determine what "mobile" is.
  var mobile = '(max-width: 600px)';

  if (window.matchMedia && window.matchMedia(mobile).matches) {
    // Send mobile event.
    ga('send', {
      hitType: 'event',        
      eventCategory: 'Form Indentifier', 
      eventAction: 'submit',    
      eventLabel: 'mobile label...',
      hitCallback: afterHitSucceeds
    });
  }
  else {
    // Send desktop event.
    ga('send', {
      hitType: 'event',        
      eventCategory: 'Form Indentifier', 
      eventAction: 'submit',    
      eventLabel: 'desktop label...',
      hitCallback: afterHitSucceeds
    });
  }

  // Once the GA hit succeeds, submit the form.
  function afterHitSucceeds() {
    $('#myform').submit();
  }
});
```

This function uses [`window.matchMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.matchMedia) to determine if a particular media query matches (allowing you to match the `@media` rule in your CSS file).

If the passed media matches, a mobile event will be sent, if the passed media doesn't match (or the browser doesn't support it) a desktop event will be sent. Note that pretty much all mobile browsers support `matchMedia` so falling back to the desktop event is a safe way to go.

Comment: Aye, jQuery is being used. Thank you for the solution. I will give a test and let you know. Accepting this answer, though. Thanks.

Comment: I've actually updated the answer because you'll probably need to stop the form from being submitted until after the GA hit succeeds. The new code reflects this.